# Locking In Unvotes

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, voting

I asked a question, and someone replied with an decent answer, so I upvoted their answer. A minute later, I discovered there might be some inaccuracies with their answer, so I un-upvoted their answer. A few more minutes later, I finally concluded the answer was correct, and tried to re-upvote their answer, but the site said my lack of a vote was now "locked in". How is this possible? It's not showing I voted at all...

Comment: Yeah I really hate this too, I hope this gets fixed.

Comment: I believe it has been stated by the SO founders that it is not an abuse of the system to edit the answer (and leave no edits) so you un-lock your vote.  I always found this a bit shady though.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot change your vote ~3 minutes after you cast the first vote, unless the post is edited.

This is a [feature by design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18360/vote-too-old-to-be-changed-but-i-havent-voted):

> To help curb "tactical-downvoting,"
>   we've changed a couple things with
>   up/down voting:
>
> - reduced the time window where you may undo a vote
> - started the time window on the first vote, even if it is now deleted
>     (your use case)
>
> So, **the clock starts ticking on the
>   first vote you make** - you get a few
>   minutes in which you may alter it, but
>   then it's locked until the target post
>   is edited.

Comment: What I don't understand is why the lack of a vote is being treated the same as an upvote or a downvote. I agree that people shouldn't be allowed to retract a vote after N minutes, but if they do retract their vote before that deadline, they should be allowed to make a vote at some unspecified point in the future. In my case, this is preventing people from making ANY vote.

Comment: It seems that this question was misunderstood. The question was not about a vote getting locked but about a non-vote getting locked. However, according to [this answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/1399/6622), the problem has been solved in the meantime.

Comment: This doesn't curb tactical downvoting at all.  The only thing it does is prevent the cheater from later undoing the damage.   [Please get rid of “vote locking”](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5120/2206)